# WordPress Genesis Theme: Changing sidebar code hook on WooCommerce product single pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

I want to change the current WooCommerce product single code structure from:

```
<div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
   <main class="content"></div>
   <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
   <main class="content">
   <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
   </div>
</div>
```

So basically putting the sidebar wrapper inside of the main content class. How can I achieve this?